# I am getting **ERROR** while RETRIEVING data in *TABLE* format

Tags: jquery, ajax

1) This is **JQuery** and **Ajax** code for retrieving data in **Table** format.

2) The problem is I am getting *Error* in *10th Line*

3) The *Error* I am getting is 
        **Uncaught TypeError: rowNew.children.eq is not a function** 
      using **Developer Tools** I have *Debugged*.

4) I have added my **code** *Below*.

5) Kindly **help** *friends*, I am *new* to **JQuery** and **Ajax**.

6)Any Idea *friends* ,how to **proceed**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tablediv").hide();
  $("#showTable").click(function(event){
      $.post('Report', function(responseJson){
          if(responseJson!=null){
              $("#reporttable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
              var table=$("#reporttable");
              $.each(responseJson, function(key,value){
                  var rowNew= $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                  rowNew.children.eq(0).text(value['VehicleRegistrationNumber']);
                  rowNew.children.eq(1).text(value['fromplace']);
                  rowNew.children.eq(2).text(value['toplace']);
                  rowNew.children.eq(3).text(value['fromtime']);
                  rowNew.children.eq(4).text(value['totime']);
                  rowNew.children.eq(5).text(value['status']);
                  rowNew.appendTo(table);
              });
          }
      });
      $("#tablediv").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you forget `()` after `children`?

Comment: I think so, I will Check with that in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution for future reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tablediv").hide();
      $("#showTable").click(function(event){
          $.post('Report', function(responseJson){
              if(responseJson!=null){
                  $("#reporttable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                  var table=$("#reporttable");
                  $.each(responseJson, function(key,value){
                      var rowNew= $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                      rowNew.children.eq(0).text(value['VehicleRegistrationNumber']);
                      rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['fromplace']);
                      rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['toplace']);
                      rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['fromtime']);
                      rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['totime']);
                      rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['status']);
                      rowNew.appendTo(table);
                  });
              }
          });
          $("#tablediv").show();
    });
});
```